# How to program a vehicle as an sdn controller?

Tags: omnet++, sdn, veins, sumo

I want to program a vehicle in OMNET++ as an SDN controller, but I don't know how to get started.

I am using SUMO, VEINS and OMNET++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to run a simulation of mobile hosts doing SDN based on the INET Framework, you can then use Veins (e.g. version 4.7.1) to have your hosts behave like vehicles. Your simulation would just need to use the `veins_inet` project.

Comment: I am using veins 4.7.1, omnet ++ 5.3 and SUMO 0.32.0 in Ubuntu 18.04. I made a documentation based installation script. Later I want to share it with the VEINS community. From what I understand veins_inet is already part of VEINS. I also need to use an LTE / 5G base station in this environment. It's possible? Only Veins LTE has these features?

Comment: I just saw your comment about VeinsLTE at https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/issues/5. The only question left to me is whether the Veins 4.7.1 i1 instance with SimuLTE would serve my purpose. What's different from veins_hetvnet?

Comment: SimuLTE+Veins can simulate a vehicle that has an LTE interface. INET+Veins can simulate a vehicle that has a WLAN interface. Veins_hetvnet can simulate a vehicle that has both.

Comment: Is veins_hetvnet compatible with sdn too?

Comment: It is compatible with INET. I do not know whether INET can do what you want to do.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Christoph. I gave up on using LTE. I want to program vehicles as sdn controller using veins, veins_inet and inet Framework, as already suggested.

I read the article "Bidirectionally Coupled Network and Road
Traffic Simulation for Enhanced IVC Analysis "and I also read the page: https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules.


Where can I find more information about veins_inet and how it communicates with SUMO?

Comment: Veins_inet enables you to use Veins as a mobility model of road traffic (and for creating/destroying hosts as vehicles depart/arrive) in INET. Just write your simulation like any other INET simulation, then swap out the mobility model